# Adobe AEM CMS - how to get a developer license to install locally to evaluate the product?

Tags: adobe, aem

As the lead architect, I had no problem installing EPiServer CMS system, installing a test site (Alloy), and start writing MVC code in Visual studio to see what it could and could not do.  This was assisted by EPiServer offering 6 video training courses which covered development, deployment hosting and enough about authoring to understand the key concepts (visitor groups, blocks, DAM etc).  Now the organisation I consulted for is spending more than £100k per month on EPiserver licenses (3 DXC instances)

Now I have to evaluate AEM for a new project and new company.  After considerable time searching for developer documentation, I found a guide to install AEM on a local machine with eclipse, Java 8 etc.  However, it needs a license.properties.  I found several posts asking how to get his, but none with a resolution. One has a link to a form which does not exist.

I filled out the sales contact form, as Adobe offer no way to contact them about AEM (no email, no chat) etc.  I got no reply.

I also posted on the AEM adobe forum, asking if where was any way for a developer or consultant to get a license to evaluate the product from a technical perspective.  I linked to a few of the older posts asking the same question, and pointed out that the links they provided were now dead.  My post was deleted by Adobe.  I have no idea why, unless they are trying to stop new customers from seeing their product before paying for it?

Any other developers or architects out there found a way to get a local dev trial license if your organisation has not purchased one?

Answer (score 1):

1. Register on their partners portal : https://solutionpartners.adobe.com
2. Request product access here (here they force you to login) - https://solutionpartners.adobe.com/download/aemform/

In about 1-2 working days you get a download link and a license key. (Last I had to request access was quite sometime back so things might have changed)